# Maintain multicolumn information when sorting a specified column

Tags: python, numpy, sorting

I am trying to sort a 2D array, data, with a size (512**2,3) where data[::,0] contains the values I would like to sort, and data[::,1] as well as data[::,2] contain the pixel numbers. I need to be able to sort the first column (data[0,::]) and change the rest of the columns so that each value in the new place has the according pixel numbers.

I have tried to sort the array and the compare the new with the previous one and rearrange the pixel number accordingly, but this is very time consuming and I was wondering whether there was a way to sort an array and take all the information of each element of the array you are sorting with it.

Comment: Look into using `np.argsort`

Comment: try `idx=np.argsort(data[:,0])` and `sdata = data[idx,:]`